# Uisng Angula2 JS not able to hit the external service?

Tags: angular

I am receiving 401 unauthorized issues when invoking my marklogic server from angular 2 JS.

Below is the code snippet i am using:

```
getPolicies() {
let username: string = 'admin';
let password: string = 'admin';
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

httpHeaders.set("Authorization", ("Bearer " + btoa(username + ":" + password)));
httpHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
httpHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


this.http.get(this.serverUrl, { 
  headers: httpHeaders
}).toPromise() 
        .then(policy => console.log("policy values:"+ policy))
        .catch(err => console.log("error value:"+ JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)));
```

}

[image]

The error can be referred to in the screenshot attached. Can you please help me provide the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The access token your sending is not getting authorized for the server

```
httpHeaders.set("Authorization", ("Bearer " + btoa(username + ":" + password)));
```

You can also try something like this if it helps: 
Try getting the access token during login and send it.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.access_token});
```